# Sending email from website WITHOUT using Google SMTP

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, email, webforms

I am producing a website for a friends company and they would like customers to be able to contact them using a form on the website that will email the query to their work email address.

All the examples I have been able to find use GMail's SMTP server. I have managed to get this to work using the code below but e-mails always appear in the inbox as from the GMail account, regardless of what I set mm.From to be. I understand that this is the downside to using GMail's SMTP server.

```
    Dim mm As MailMessage = New MailMessage()
    mm.From = New MailAddress("customer@test.com")
    mm.Subject = "Test Email"
    mm.Body = "<p>This is a test email</p>"
    mm.IsBodyHtml = True
    mm.To.Add(New MailAddress("info@myCompany.com"))

    Dim smtp As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient()

    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtp.EnableSsl = True
    Dim NetworkCred As NetworkCredential = New System.Net.NetworkCredential()
    NetworkCred.UserName = "mycompany@gmail.com"
    NetworkCred.Password = "myPassword"
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
    smtp.Port = 587

    Try
        smtp.Send(mm)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    End Try
```

I would like the senders e-mail address to appear in the from field so users can just click reply when a message comes in.

The business e-mail account they have is provided by GoDaddy and I have tried entering the SMTP and account details in the code but I get the following error:

System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: net_io_connectionclosed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you use own credentials, do not set `UseDefaultCredentials` to True.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any SMTP service that you have access to.  So if GMail's doesn't do what you need, try another one.  (The settings for that other one may be different, check with the service host for details.)

**However**, one thing you can definitely do in your code is set a `ReplyTo` address.  `From` is only one header in the message, there are others that can be used.  A `ReplyTo` header tells the email client that replies should be sent to a given email address.

```
mm.ReplyTo = New MailAddress("customer@test.com")
```